# Typeahead remote call is triggering even if there are datas in local/prefetch

Tags: ajax, jquery, typeahead

The remote call is  trigging even if there are values in prefetch/local data.

Sample Code:

```
var jsonObj = ["Toronto", "Montreal", "Calgary", "Ottawa", "Edmonton", "Peterborough"]; 

$('input.countries-cities').typeahead([
    {
        name: 'Canada',
        local: jsonObj,
        remote: {
            url: 'http://localhost/typeahead/ajaxcall.php?q=QUERY',
            cache: true
        },
        limit: 3,
        minLength: 1,
        header: '<h3>Canada</h3>'
    }
]);
```

What i expect is trigger remote call only if there are no matches in local. But each time i type locations the remote call is getting triggered. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: These are the js files included:jquery-1.9.1.min.js,typeahead.js,hogan-2.0.0.js

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a couple months old, but I ran into a similar issue and found [this answer](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/355#issuecomment-21361660).

The problem is that your `limit` is set to 3 and your search is turning up less results than your limit, thus triggering the remote call. If you had set your `limit` to 1, you wouldn't get a remote call unless there were no results.

Not a great design IMO, since you probably still want to see 3 results if there are 3 results. And worse, say your local/prefetch results only return 1 result...if your remote returns the same result, it will be duplicated in your list. I haven't found a solution to that problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

In bloodhound.js replace

```
matches.length < this.limit ? cacheHit = ...
```

by

```
matches.length < 1 ? cacheHit = ...
```